# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

trying to learn some Vue.js.
Basically I'm just trying to display the title of the room.
As you can see I can see the whole array in the console but I'm not able to print title from it...
Any ideas?

**GetRooms.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
    <h1>All rooms</h1>
    <li class="py-2" v-for="room in rooms">
        {{ room.title }}
    </li>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                rooms:[]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getAllRooms();
        },
        methods:{
            getAllRooms(){
                this.rooms = [];
                this.$http.get('/get-rooms').then(function (response) {
                    this.rooms = response.json();
                } , function (response) {

                })
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Vue Dev tools]

Comment: Did you look in Vue Dev Tools what content in `rooms` of  a `data` scetion?

Comment: @Anatoly I updated my post with a screenshot, take a look.

Comment: well, it looks like you're expecting `rooms` to be an array, but it's an object with an undefined `context` prop -- so Vue can't find `title` on undefined `context`.

Comment: I think the `response` is the array, you don't have to use `response.json` or you can do it with async/await
`async getAllRooms(){
                let resp = await this.$http.get('/get-rooms');
                this.rooms = resp.data;
            }`

Comment: Thanks a lot @jjchiw ! That works :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting `rooms` to be an `array`, but it's an `object` with an `undefined` `context` prop -- so Vue can't find `title` on `undefined` `context` when it iterates over `rooms` in the `v-for`.

Answer (score 0):

in v-for use :key
    
also use axios it will convert it auto to json and you need 1st call the data it self then convert it to a json format. 
use vue dev tools to understand better.
it does seems you calling an object into an array although this should still works. you`re just getting an array of objects and it should show you an object iteration so probably a bad http call